# How do i fix those errors - redirecting to my server (maby)

Tags: php, mysql

## The Code

```
<?php 

//This is the directory where images will be saved 
$target = "images/"; 
$target = $target . basename ($_FILES['photo']['did']); 

$did = $_POST['did']; 
$name = $_POST['dname']; 
$disc = $_POST['ddisc']; 
$price = $_POST['dprice']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['did']); 

print_r($_POST); 
session_start(); 
$con = mysql_connect("","restoraunt","123456"); 
if (!$con) 
{ 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db("restoraunt", $con); 

//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `menu` VALUES ('$did', '$name', '$disc', '$price','a','$pic')") ; 



/*************************/ 
//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

//Tells you if its all ok 
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['did']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
} 
else { 

//Gives and error if its not 
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
} 
/**************************/ 



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) 
{ 
die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo "1 record added"; 

mysql_close($con); 

?>
```

## The errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: photo in
>   D:\WEB\Sites\Restoraunt\addDish.php on
>   line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: photo in
>   D:\WEB\Sites\Restoraunt\addDish.php on
>   line 17
>
> ```
> Array ( 
>     [did] => 90
>     [dname] => uhh 
>     [ddisc] => jhjjhh
>     [dprice] => 12
>     [dcateg] => Appetiser
>     [photo] => Penguins.jpg 
>     [Add] => Add 
> )
> ```
>
> Notice:
>   Undefined index: photo in
>   D:\WEB\Sites\Restoraunt\addDish.php on
>   line 40 Sorry, there was a problem
>   uploading your file. Notice: Undefined
>   variable: sql in
>   D:\WEB\Sites\Restoraunt\addDish.php on
>   line 55 Error: Query was empty

Comment: `Undefined index` means the index key of your array doesn't exist. Try a `print_r($_FILES);` as the first line of your code to see what your `$_FILES` array contains.

Comment: `$_FILES['photo']` vs `$_FILES['uploadedfile']`. I'm guessing you want `uploadedfile`.

Comment: $_FILES['photo']['did'] What is this?

Answer (score 1):

The $_FILES array has a specific format and layout, and your keys, such as `did`, won't exist in there. The standard layout is:

```
$_FILES = array(
    'name of your input type="file" field' => array(
          'name' => 'name of file on client machine',
          'type' => 'mime type of file, as provided by the client',
          'size' => 'size of uploaded file',
          'tmp_name' => 'name of server-side temporary file the upload was stored in',
          'error' => 'error code of upload operation'
    )
);
```

AS such, `$_FILES['photo']['did']` will return an invalid index, since there's no `did` element in the _FILES array.

Full details of the array's structure, and the error codes, are [here][1] and [here][2], respectively.

The SQL error is due to the fact that you're trying to run the query twice. Once with the query string directly in the `mysql_query()` function call as a parameter, and again later using an undefined `$sql` variable.

As well, you're refering to two seperate file uploads:

```
$_FILES['photo']
$_FILES['uploadedfile']
```

in different places. Which one should it be?
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
[2]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Thank you
It shoud be $_FILES['photo']

fixed $sql problem

Still have the error about 'photo index... :('

Comment: You're not checking if the file uploaded successfully at all, and just assuming it did. Before you do ANY of the database stuff, you should at MININUM have `if ($_FILES['photo']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { die("File upload failed"); }`.

Answer (score 0):

First advice : never trust user, allways validate and filter inputs

```
$did = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'did');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dname');
$disc = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ddisc');
$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dprice');
$photo = (isset($_FILES['photo'])) ? $_FILES['photo'] : null;
```

Then, `$_FILES['photo']` and `$sql` do not exist. Allways test existence with `isset()`, `empty()` ...

Comment: Thanks
I thought that &_FILES created like $_POST - from html submit form
How to define $_FILE in that case ?

Comment: did you set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute of your form ?

Answer (score 0):

fixed most of the errors - still got one

## the error:

Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in D:\WEB\Sites\Restoraunt\addDish.php on line 33
The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directoryError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Resource id #2' at line 1

## the code:

```
[PHP]<?php
session_start();

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target_path = "images/";
$target = $target_path . basename ($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$did = $_POST['did'];
$name = $_POST['dname'];
$disc = $_POST['ddisc'];
$price = $_POST['dprice'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

$con = mysql_connect("","restoraunt","123456"); // àéôä ùí äùøú ùìê, localhost àå îùäå?
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("restoraunt", $con);

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `menu` VALUES ('$did', '$name', '$disc', '$price','a','$pic')") ;
// àéôä ùîåú äòîåãåú áèáìä ùìê áãàèàáééñ?
// insert into menu (c1, c2, c3, c4) values('$c1', '$c2', '$c3', '$c4');

/*************************/
//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
/**************************/

if (!mysql_query($con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>[/PHP]
```